# Determinant of matrix $A^3 + 2A^2 - A - 5I$ Given the eigenvalues of A

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

So A is a 3 by 3 matrix with eigenvalues -1, 1, 2. And I have to find the determinant of $$A^3 + 2A^2 - A - 5I$$

Let $u$ be the eigenvector for the eigenvalue -1. Let
$S = A^3 + 2A^2 - A - 5I$ then
$Su = \lambda u$.
$=(A^3 + 2A^2 - A - 5I)u\\
=A^3u + 2A^2u - Au - 5u$

Where do I go from here?

Comment: can you do it if $A$ is diagonal?

Comment: You could cheat by assuming that the question has an answer.  Under this baseless assumption, any matrix with the given eigenvalues would be enough to get the answer, so just choose the diagonal matrix that has the given eigenvalues and compute the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say that $v_{-1}$, $v_1$, and $v_2$ are the eigenvectors of $A$. Using your notation,
$$
Sv_i=A^3v_i+2A^2v_i-Av_i-5Iv_i=i^3v_i+2i^2v_i-iv_i-5v_i=(i^3+2i^2-i-5)v_i
$$
So for each eigenvalue $i$ of $A$, $i^3+2i^2-i-5$ is an eigenvalue of $S$. Plugging in $-1,1,2$, we get $-3,-3,$ and $9$ as eigenvalues for the $S$. But the determinant of a matrix is the product of its eigenvalues, so $\det S=-3\cdot -3\cdot 9 = 81$.

Comment: Was the $-2i$ a mistake (since it's only $-A$) or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo-thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

As $A$ has eigen values $-1,1,2$ you can actually see $A$ as $\begin{pmatrix}-1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&2\end{pmatrix}$

If this is the case, what would be $A^3$??  what would be $A^2$??

$A^3=\begin{pmatrix}-1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&8\end{pmatrix}$ and $A^2=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&4\end{pmatrix}$

So what would be $A^3+2A^2-A-5I$??

what would be determinant of $A^3+2A^2-A-5I$??

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

i) the determinant of a matrix equals the prodct of its eigenvalues.

ii) every matrix satisfies its characteristic polynomial.

|